# LINQ join query returns matched records

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
class loan
{
  public money Value{set; get;}
  public int id{set; get;}
  public int CustomerId{set; get;}
}

class loanPayment
{
  public int id{set; get;} 
  public int LoanId{set; get;}
  public money Value{set; get;}
}
```

I tried this LINQ code :

```
//_CustomerId is a parameter
 DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
  var query =
           (from l in context.Loan
            where l.CustomerId == _CustomerId
            join lp in context.LoanPayment on l.Id equals lp.LoanId into j1
            from Payments in j1
            select Payments 
            ).ToList();
```

Now my problem is that this code will return only `loan` records that have at least one `payment` but I want to have records join with it's payments and also I want Loans that haven't any payment yet how can I do this ?

Something like this :

[image]

First loan has a payment but second doesn't.

Comment: What is DatabaseContext()? Is that returning an EF data context? If so, why wouldn't you define the links in your model, so you could simply use navigational properties? That way you wouldn't have a such problem either. In Linq, you seldom need to use joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Left-Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) and `DefaultIfEmpty` method, something like this:

```
var query = from l in context.Loan
            join lp in context.LoanPayment on l.Id equals lp.LoanId into j1
            from lp in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Loan = l, LoanPayment = lp == null ? "(No LoanPayment)" 
           : lp.Id.ToString() };
```

Or if you want to select the whole object of `LoanPayment`:

```
select new { Loan = l, LoanPayment = lp ?? new loanPayment() };
```

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need any joins in Linq for relations. You just need to define your relations in the model (generators do this automatically for you, provided you have set your relations in the database itself - or you do it directly in the model say with code first). Here is a sample showing why you don't need it, and how to utilize the navigational properties instead (based on MS SQL Northwind sample database):

```
string defaultConString = @"server=.\SQLExpress2012;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes;";

void Main()
{
    var ctx = new MyContext(defaultConString);
    var customerId = "FISSA";

    var customer = ctx.Customers
        .Include(c => c.Orders)
        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == customerId);

    if (customer != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{customer.CompanyName}, Orders: {customer.Orders.Count()}");
        //      var frmMusteriSiparisleri = new Form { Text = string.Format("[{0}] - Siparisler", customerId) };
        //      var dgvSiparisler = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, ReadOnly = true, DataSource = customer.Orders.ToList() };
        //      frmMusteriSiparisleri.Controls.Add(dgvSiparisler);
        //      frmMusteriSiparisleri.ShowDialog();
    }
}


public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString)
       : base(connectionString)
    { }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}



public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShippedDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

[Table("Order Details")]
public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public Int16 Quantity { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: OK this is perfect but my database is SQLite. and it has so many limitations in ling.I don't Know if SQLite supports this technique or not.maybe i must try it. thanks.

Comment: @Mamad, yes you should try it, because now I don't have time to write a full sample for you. You can also use Linq To SQL for SQLite (interestingly Linq support for SQLite is much before than Entity Framework). Just google "Linq to entity framework sqlite".